# How do I check if any multiple variables are true?

Tags: javascript

For instance, say I have a list of 6 boolean variables. If any 3 of these are `true`, do something.

In my particular case, I'm looking at something like this:

```
var categoriesClicked = [];
if (category1Clicked) {
  categoriesClicked.push('category1Clicked');
}
if (category2Clicked) {
  categoriesClicked.push('category2Clicked');
}
...
if (categoriesClicked.length > 3) {
  //User clicked at least 3 categories, do something
}
```

Would this be the best way?

Comment: It should work without any issue: are you talking about optimizing the code? Then you might want to look at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Terry Oh no, I was just wondering if this is the easiest way. Sorry!

Comment: Yes, there's an easier way, push the values to `categoriesClicked` array where ever you're currently giving the value to the variables you're checking.

Comment: What are you trying to solve with this? Solution will depend on its purpose.

Comment: `length > 3` That would be 4 minimum

Comment: @faithfull Essentially, when a user clicks 3 unique elements on a webpage (categories), fire an event. This would be to prevent the user from selecting/deselecting the same element 3 times.

Answer (score 3):

You can abuse the `+` operator, as that converts `true` to `1` and `false` to `0`. ([Specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-addition-operator-plus))

Just add your booleans together and see if they equal to `3`

```js
let b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6;
b1 = b2 = b3 = true;
b4 = b5 = b6 = false;

console.log(b1 + b2 + b3 + b4 + b5 + b6 === 3);
```

Comment: Furthermore, you can have `arr = [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6]` and then do a simple `arr.reduce((a, b) => a+b, 0)`. Ideally you already have access to a `sum` function, as you don't need to keep defining it, in which case you only have `arr.reduce(sum, 0)`

Comment: @VLAZ if you have a sum function `sum(arr)`

Comment: @aloisdgmovingtocodidact.com I was thinking about a `sum = (a, b) => a + b`. Well, likely a curried version so you can also call it like `arr.map(sum(3))`. I find it more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of an array of the values, then filter the *true* values to get the *length*.

**Demo:**

```js
var valueArray = [true, true, false, true, false, false];
var trueValCount = valueArray.filter(v => v).length;
if (trueValCount === 3) {
  console.log('Has 3 true value');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can keep track of count using numeric value. unnecessary creating map would not be suggestible.  like

```
var count=0;
if(category1Clicked){
 count = count+1;
}
if(category2Clicked){
 count = count+1;
}
...
if(count >= 3){
//User clicked at least 3 categories, do something
}
```